# Find the equilibrium point for a single neural network layer

Tags: fixed-point-theorems, nash-equilibrium, fixed-points, fixed-point-arithmetics

Given a matrix $\mathbf{W}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and a vector $\mathbf{b}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, find the equilibirum for the following single-layer neural network:
$$
f(\mathbf{x})=\text{ReLU}(\mathbf{Wx+b}),
$$
where $\text{ReLU}(\cdot)=\text{max}(\cdot,\mathbf{0})$ is an element-wise activation function, and the goal is actually to find a set of $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that:
$$
f(\mathbf{x})-\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}.
$$

How to determine the existence of equilibrium points and calculate them efficiently?

---

**My Efforts:**

I construct a new cost function:
$$
J(\mathbf{x})=\lVert f(\mathbf{x})-\mathbf{x}\rVert_2^2 =\lVert \text{max}(\mathbf{Wx+b},\mathbf{0})-\mathbf{x}\rVert_2^2,
$$

and try to find its minimum points, but it's still hard for me to solve this.

This problem may be turned into a limitation:

$$
\mathbf{x}^*=\underset{k\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\mathbf{x}_k,
$$

where $\mathbf{x}_k=f\left( \mathbf{x}_{k-1} \right)$ with giving some starting point $\mathbf{x}_{0}$, but I have no idea about how to solve this completely or inductively.